# Using aldeed:autoform with iron:router

Tags: meteor, collections, routes, iron-router, meteor-autoform

I added aldeed:autoform for my meteor project by including following packages.

```
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
```

After the inclusion, the routing of the application is crashed. For every route it says that the routes are not defined.[image: error message from iron:route]

And after I remove the above aldeed:autoform packages from the project, the routing worked as expected. I want to know whether these two packages are incompatible or how to get the project working with these packages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that IronRouter and Autoform are compatible​ with each other (it is a common combination).  I'm wondering if you are having issues because of how you installed `collection2`.  Per the latest Autoform [README.md](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/devel/README.md)...

> AutoForm 6.0 is now available and requires switching your app to using the SimpleSchema package from NPM and aldeed:collection2-core package.

I have not tested this but perhaps try following these instructions instead.

Answer (score 0):

there should be more than 'no routes defined' error. any js error will break the routing. can you paste the whole console messages here?